# Is java array elements always stored in contiguous memory incase of reference types?

Tags: java

I've read that **The elements of an array are stored in a contiguous memory location** . Is it always the case ? I understand this is the case with array of primitives. I'm a bit confused about array of objects. An array of objects basically contains reference of the real objects right? references must be stored in contiguous locations but what about the real objects are they really stored in contiguous locations?

Comment: There's already a great answer below, so just to add a some context: in Java, objects are not tied to one location in memory - they are frequently moved around  (this is invisible to programmers, as their references remain valid and unchanging) - as part of a complex performance trade-off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it always the case ?

Yes, but keep reading.

> I'm a bit confused about array of objects. An array of objects basically contains reference of the real objects right? references must be stored in contiguous locations but what about the real objects are they really stored in contiguous locations?

Exactly, what the array contains is *object references*, not the objects themselves. Think of object references as being similar to `long` values that tell the JVM where the object is elsewhere in memory (it's more complicated than that, but that's a useful mental model). The object references are stored in the array's contiguous memory block. The *objects* are elsewhere, and may or may not be stored in contiguous memory (probably not).

So for instance, say we have:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

In memory we'll get something like:

```
               +−−−−−−−+
a: Ref51234−−−>| int[] |
               +−−−−−−−+
               | 1     |
               | 2     |
               | 3     |
               +−−−−−−−+
```

`a` contains a reference to the array, which is elsewhere in memory and has a contiguous data block containing `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Now let's look at an object array (where the `Example` class stores the given constructor parameter as a private `x` field):

```
Example[] a = new Example[] { new Example(1), new Example(2), new Example(3) };
```

That might give us something like this:

```
               +−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−+
a: Ref51234−−−>| Example[] |     +−−−>| Example |
               +−−−−−−−−−−−+     |    +−−−−−−−−−+
               | Ref81372  |−−−−−+    | x: 1    |
               | Ref96315  |−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−+   
               | Ref12975  |−−+ |                   +−−−−−−−−−+
               +−−−−−−−−−−−+  | +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| Example |
                              |                     +−−−−−−−−−+
                              |                     | x: 2    |
                              |                     +−−−−−−−−−+
                              |   +−−−−−−−−−+
                              +−−>| Example |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−+
                                  | x: 3    |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−+
```

Some environments have *packed arrays* as an adjunct. For instance, IBM documents packed arrays for its environment [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/7.1?topic=dpo-packed-arrays-1).

Comment: If the array contains `String`s then also it would be in contiguous memory block?

Comment: @Turtle - No, strings are objects in Java.

Comment: @Turtle strings are objects and they are immutable. if you are changing a string it creates a new object rather than changing its content. you can fix this by using `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` which are mutable.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.